# If you add a collaborator to a github public repo can they delete or damage anything?

Tags: github

We are setting up a open source project which we would like to allow freelancers to develop alongside us without damaging anything.

In general can the collaborators make changes to repositories without admins being able to check the changes over before code is merged into master.

What is the best method to use to prevent the repository from user damage  whilst working with a large number of public freelance developers / users?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can give them read-only permission. They can fork to their own account and start working on that code. Then after finishing a feature they can create a pull request to merge it back to the main repo.

Comment: i tried to add a user as a collaborator there was no option for read-only or admin just one button to add a collaborator are there more options i am missing. How do larger project have so many  collaborators listed?  Do collaborators still have to fork in order to push or to create a pull request

Comment: I created a 2nd test account on github and added myself as a collaborator. on the 2nd account i was able to clone yet i got permisson denied when i tried to push on the command line.

Comment: If it's public repository, then you got readonly-permission by default.

Comment: ah ok sure if i add collaborators to the list are these just for show really. and they only have readonly access unless they fork and create a pull request for acceptance?

Comment: as i think it would be good to have the collaborators listed if this is how it can work.

Comment: what i mean is if it's public repository. You don't really need to add them to collaborators list, they can see the repo and can fork it. If it's a private repository, then you need to create a team and assign readonly permission.

Comment: ok thanks do you know users forrk and create pull requests if  they will appear in the contributors list count. i  just realised github use two different  definitions which maybe  different "Collaborators" and "Contributors". I have seen on some repos they have lists of avatars of developers who have contributed to their project. If users fork and create pull requests will they appear as contributors which is our aim?

Comment: I think i found my answer here :) - https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Contributors-vs-Collaborators

Answer (score 0):

For a Personal account on Github, there are two types of 'roles' - Owner and Collaborator.

For a full list of who can do what - see here:

https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository

To answer your question - "No - A collaborator cannot delete a repository"